# No source completion for templates and routes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I installed the latest version (2.2.0) of the Scala Plugin for IntelliJ 15.0.3 Community Edition but I have no source completion for my view templates or my routing-configuration.

IntelliJ treats my view templates as plain html and my routes as plain text!?

What am I doing wrong?

CoffeeScript files are also not recognized and I am being asked how to open .coffee files.

I just created a new play project with "activator new" and opened it with IntelliJ.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You imported (with auto import) or just opened

Comment: According to this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE

However, the option "Play 2.x" project does not exist anymore, I only find "Activator". Also if I try to create an new project, in the Scala Category are only the options "Scala", "SBT" and "Activator".

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new project with activator (docs:[Creating a new application](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/NewApplication))
2. In IntelliJ open `File\New\Poject from existing Source`
3. Select folder with project
4. Select `Import project from external model` -> SBT
5. Check `Use auto-import` and click `Finish`

Comment: Did not help. :-( I get exactly the same as before. I added a screenshot of the newly created project to my OP. As you see the files aren't recognized as view templates...

Comment: Do you mean this? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7080?pr=

This is not compatible with my IntelliJ version. The built-in plugin finder doesn't list it and if I try to install it from disk, I get the message "The plugin is not compatible with your version".

Comment: well, actually I saw this dependency: com.intellij.modules.ultimate ...
So no Play Framework development with the Community Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Community edition DOES NOT support frameworks.

Sorry for bad news anyway you can check it on the comparison chart at JetBrain's page.